# Simple exercise of Lp convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I found this exercise:

- Given $(X,\mu)$ space with measure, $(u_n) \subset L^1(X,\mu)$, $u_n \rightarrow u$ almost everywhere, $|u_n|\leq |u|$ almost everywhere, prove that $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^1$.

I think this is precisely the Lebesgue theorem, so applying it you obtain:

$lim_n \int_X u_n d\mu = \int_X u d\mu $

$lim_n \int_X (u_n-u) d\mu =0 $

$lim_n \int_X |u_n-u| d\mu =0 $

which is the definition for $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^1$.

Can it be the proof? Thanks.

Comment: You need $u \in L^1$ as an assumption too.

Comment: Why $u$ is not $L^1$, even if $(u_n) \in L^1$ and $(u_n) \rightarrow u$?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. For $\displaystyle\int_{X}(u_{n}-u)d\mu\rightarrow 0$ does not entail $\displaystyle\int_{X}|u_{n}-u|d\mu\rightarrow 0$, but the latter will imply the former. Rather, you may look at $|u_{n}-u|\leq|u_{n}|+|u|\leq 2|u|$ and apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to the whole $|u_{n}-u|$ to finish the job.

Comment: I think to use the bound you wish you need the convergence to be uniform, and even then you'd need to have a bigger RHS than $2|u|$ because the distance between $u_n$ and $u$ exists, even if small.